# Email to Whatsapp user

Tags: email, gateway, whatsapp

I have an alert service which currently sends me email alerts. I would like to redirect these emails so that they appear as messages to me in whatsapp.

My first idea would be to follow the email to SMS gateway approach. I see some mention of Whatsapp API but I have not fully researched it.

Is there a current service for this? Or do I need to perhaps code a PHP gateway on one of my web servers to receive emails and then convert them and send via the Whatsapp API?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

https://www.whatsmate.net/whatsapp-gateway-api.html

They are offering API to send messages directly to whatsapp gateway, so that the message will be delivered as whatsapp message.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: @WaiHaLee so we do prefer just link answer before 1:1 quoting? good to know thx, that makes lifes easier ;)

Comment: @user how does the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28164819) deviates from the original intent of the post?